# What is the difference between these two sections of code?

Tags: java

First example

```
int windowStart = 0;

for (int i = 0; i + windowSize < fileArray.size(); i++) {
  ArrayList <Character> window = new ArrayList <Character> ();
  for (int s = windowStart; s <= windowStart + windowSize; s++) {
    window.add(fileArray.get(s));
  }
  windowStart++;
}
```

VS.

second example

```
int ind = 0;
for (int i = 0; i + windowSize < fileArray.size(); i++) {
  for (int b = ind; b <= windowSize + ind; b++) {
    window.add(fileArray.get(b));
  }
  ind++;
}
```

The first one throws an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` while the second one does not and works just fine. `fileArray` is the same for both, but for 2. the `window` array is defined as an attribute, while for the first one, the "window" array is defined inside the method (and the for loop). Does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm going back to my "Where's Waldo" book instead.

Comment: at what line of code is the error?

Comment: The error is at the `window.add(fileArray.get(s));` line in the first example.

Comment: What's the value for `windowSize`?

Comment: try going with the debugger and check `windowSize` value and make sure it is initialized correctly

Comment: What's the `fileArray.size()` value?

Comment: Ok, can you post the **full** stacktrace of the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` please?

Comment: Instead of an `ArrayList<Character>` consider using a StringBuilder which is a class designed to hold a collection of characters (it is much more efficient, but is a better choice because it has a number of text handling functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for adding a value to a list. The problem is that a value of `s` is equal or greater then the actual size of the `fileArray` array or list.

And because the loops in both examples are equivalent, the problem should be found outside the lines of code you've just posted.

Try to debug (break on `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you are using an IDE, otherwise add some simple `System.out.println` statements to find out, why `s` is greater than expected.

Comment: By the way, @Andreas_D, I am currently banned from posting questions, can you try undeleting some of my posts? I didn't know about the auto-ban rule and not being able to post is so painful.

Comment: @illuminati - I wasn't able to find your deleted posts or questions, I'd have to play with the database interface (custom queries) but It needs more than one to undelete a question. You can't undelete them yourself? Upvoted one of your answers where you edited your text after a downvote. Maybe it already helped..

Comment: I can't undelete them myself. I read that you need 10k reputation to view deleted posts.

Answer (score 0):

From the first example, from what you're telling me:

- `windowSize` = 30.
- `fileArray.size()` = 235.

Then, your first for loop will terminate when `i + windowSize > 235` (which means i = 236 - 30 = 206`.

You will realize that `windowStart` gets incremented inside the first `for-loop`, so eventually, `windowStart` will increment `205` times (starting from 0).

At that point, the 2nd `for-loop` will count (`windowStart = 205`) and your condition `s <= windowStart + windowSize` will be (`s = 205 + 30` which equals `235`), which satisfies the condition in the loop, and you're saying `fileArray.get(s)` which means, `fileArray.get(235)`, and you're getting a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I'm assuming that `windowSize` is not the same on the 2nd example, but I can't tell you that until I have seen the full source code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `windowSize` is a constant that is the same on both sections of code.

Comment: Then `fileArray.size()` changes.

Comment: It is a constant as well. `fileArray` is the same for both sections of code.

Comment: I suggest replacing example 1 to example 2 on both cases and run and see if it doesn't break.